# UIPopOverScreen troubles

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Recently I have taken interest in making a popover screen. In my Navigation bar I made this button and when I click on it it should make a popover screen appear.
So I started searching for a usefull tutorial and yet I found mostly tutorials made with interface builder, which is not what I want. So I started experimenting on my own.

This is my result:

First I set the necessary properties in the MainVC.h
Also mind the

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ThePopOverVC.h"

@interface PopoverPrototypeViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
{
    ThePopOverVC *popover;
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    UIButton *popoverButton;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) ThePopOverVC *popover;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *popoverButton;

- (void)popoverActivation;

@end
```

Then I set up my view in the MainVC.m
It prepares the view for the popoverscreen when pressing a button.

```
#import "PopoverPrototypeViewController.h"

@implementation PopoverPrototypeViewController

@synthesize popover;
@synthesize popoverController;
@synthesize popoverButton;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    popover = [[ThePopOverVC alloc] init];
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popover];
    popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 300);
    popoverController.delegate = self;

    self.popoverButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 400, 100)];
    self.popoverButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.popoverButton setTitle:@"Click me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.popoverButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popoverActivation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.popoverButton];


}

- (void)popoverActivation
{
    if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {

        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    } else {

        UIBarButtonItem *settingsBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.popoverButton];
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:settingsBarButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

    }
}

- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    NSLog(@"something");
}
```

Ok, the MainVC should be setup, now it's time to show the popoverContentViewController.
For my experiment I just want it to be an empty view with just a different backgroundColor.

So the popoverVC.h is empty:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThePopOverVC : UIViewController

@end
```

My popoverVC.m is equally empty except for the backgroundColor change:

```
#import "ThePopOverVC.h"

@implementation ThePopOverVC

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

You would say this shouldn't be too hard. But yet I'm experiencing problems loading the project.
I'm getting the following warning: *warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.*

Well here comes the question:
What have I overlooked? What have I done wrong and how can I make this simple prototype work?

//---*EDIT*---//
OK, I'm a bloody idiot for overlooking this one.

```
[super loadView];
```

The super loadView wasn't called and gave me this simple problem.
I edited the code so it works properly now.
Use this as a tutorial on how to make UIPopOverScreens if you will (or whatever).
Ref: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

Comment: You can refer Ray Wenderlich blogs for `UIPopoverViewController`. http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[super loadView];
```

Was missing from ThePopOverVC.m 
Pretty silly to overlook.. but yeah, it works now.